read from file to a struct containing an atomic variable
I have a shared memory-mapped file that starts by some payload of type:
struct header
{
    unsigned long long version = 0;
    std::atomic<bool> ok = false;
    // other fields
};

As far as I know, std::atomic<bool> is lock-free and thus, according to some other stackoverflow answer I can "cast" a pointer to header and rw will work just fine, and I can apply atomic operations over it. For example:
_fd = open("/dev/shm/myshfile", O_RDWR | O_CREAT | O_CLOEXEC, S_IRUSR | S_IWUSR);

void* ptr = mmap(nullptr, 4 * 1024 + _sz,
      PROT_READ | PROT_WRITE, MAP_SHARED, _fd, 0);

header* hdr = static_cast<header*>(ptr);
 
if (!hdr->ok) {
   // bla bla bla
   hdr->ok = true;
}

There is code regarding flocks that I have omitted for brevity (to take a shared or exclusive lock according to whether I want to read or write to the file) and some other various checks, but in general, I have to do some work to "initialize" or "sanitize" the file in case it's empty or for some other reason, which means that I can't be sure the file is big enough to mmap the header.
So I'm thinking of reading the header without mmaping like this:
header hdr = {};
int bytes_read = read(_fd, &hdr, sizeof(hdr)); // (1)

if (bytes_read != sizeof(hdr) || "headers contents are not ok") {
   flock(_fd, LOCK_EXCL);
   refill_file_from_scratch();
   _hdr = /* mmap as before */;
   new (_hdr) header();
   _hdr->ok = true;
}

Now, the question, the line at (1) is it safe? Can I just "read" to a struct containing an atomic and then use the atomic safely?
UPDATE:
The conversation have moved about whether std::atomic is trivially copyable or not (it's not). However, given this code:
int fd = creat("path", S_IRUSR | S_IWUSR);

auto* buf = mmap(nullptr, sizeof(header), PROT_READ | PROT_WRITE, MAP_SHARED, _fd, 0);

auto* hdr = new (buf) header;
hdr->ok = true;

unsigned char buf2[sizeof(header)];
memcpy(buf2, buf, sizeof(header));
auto* hdr2 = (header*)buf2;

Am I even copying objects of type std::atomic<bool>? Because I'm only casting buffers. Right?

std::atomic is not trivially copyable, it requires a proper contsruction, and therefore I don't think it is valid in general to cast a buffer to a struct containing it. It might work if the buffer actually contains such a struct contructed properly, but why is it related to being lock-free ?

@wohlstad I read that if an atomic variable is "always lock free", then I can cast a pointer to the atomic safely (as far as the corresponding buffer has that guarantee and the object has been properly construted there previously). And since std::atomic<bool>::is_always_free is true, then I know I can do it, but I don't know if calls to read will have the same kind of guarantee for atomic variables. I guess so but I'm not sure.

fwiw, std::is_trivially_copyable tells you whether you can memcpy instances, and that is indeed true, at least here https://godbolt.org/z/4Y1eKdqxf

@463035818_is_not_an_ai my MSVC 2022 (c++ 17 or 20) claims that std::is_trivially_copyable_v<std::atomic<bool>> is 0 (unlike gcc). This is strange - I thought that trivial copyability is defined either way by the standard.

@wohlstad they dont "claim". It can be either 0 or 1. Why do you think it is strange?

@wohlstad for the primary tempalte std::atomic<T> there is a requirement that std::trivially_copyable<T> is true but I didnt find similar statement for std::atomic<T> itself

@wohlstad Maybe it's not because the compiler itself, but because of the arch and/or OS where the code is executed? Maybe msvc can't offer a trivially-copyable implementation of std::atomic<bool> because of the execution context? Just guessing.

@463035818_is_not_an_ai I used "claim" in a figurative way. As I said I found it strange because I believed (maybe wrongly) that the standard dictates trivial copyablity of such types.

I posted a question regarding std::atomic<bool> trivial coptabilty - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78384904/is-stdatomicbool-trivially-copyable.

I think the only one that's guaranteed to be lock-free is atomic_flag, not atomic< bool >

I believe the bool itself is more problematic than std::atomic here.
Regardless of what std::is_trivially_copyable says for std::atomic (which seems to be a subject of a defect report), it should be safe in practice, as long as you don't have any concurrent accesses to the same variable. Access through [unsigned] char is exempt from strict aliasing, and I don't think there's any platform that stores anything else in std::atomic in addition to the value it contains (as long as the type is small enough to make atomic lock-free). There may or may not be some quirk in the standard that makes it technically illegal, but it would be a purely theoretical issue.)
A bigger problem is that if you read an invalid bit pattern into a bool (not 0 or 1), the code using it might break in unexpected ways.

any platform that stores anything else in std::atomic in addition to the value it contains - In general, for large T such that is_lock_free is false, some platforms (e.g. MSVC until their next ABI change) do put additional stuff inside the std::atomic object itself.  You can static_assert( sizeof(bool) == sizeof(std::atomic<bool>) ) to check that there isn't extra stuff, and to document the assumption you're making.  (Which should be fine for lock-free std::atomic.)

Or  or use plain bool and do the atomic accesses with C++20 std::atomic_ref, then you're never messing with the object-representation of a std::atomic object.  (Or actually alignas (std::atomic_ref<bool>::required_alignment) bool ok - it's possible some platforms might want an atomic bool aligned at the start of a 4-byte word even if the bool is only 1 byte.)

std::is_trivially_copyable is the trait that tells you if you can safely memcopy the bytes of one instance to another.
I tried here:
#include <atomic>
#include <iostream>
#include <type_traits>
struct header
{
    unsigned long long version = 0;
    std::atomic<bool> ok = false;
    // other fields
};
int main(){
    std::cout << std::atomic<bool>::is_always_lock_free << "\n";
    std::cout << std::is_trivially_copyable_v<std::atomic<bool>> << "\n";
    std::cout << std::is_trivially_copyable_v<header> << "\n";    
}

To receive output:
1
1
1

From cppreference:

Objects of trivially-copyable types that are not potentially-overlapping subobjects are the only C++ objects that may be safely copied with std::memcpy or serialized to/from binary files with std::ofstream::write() / std::ifstream::read().

The "potentially-overlapping" part is not std::trivially_understandable but fortunately is not relevant here.

std::trivially_understandable :D
